# Joomla - Documentation on input variables and datatypes of events

Tags: events, plugins, joomla

I usually don't ask such rudimentary questions but I've spent an hour scouring through the [documentation page](http://docs.joomla.org/) of Joomla and have yet to find anything that can describe to me what the "article", "context", etc, input variables contain say [onContentPrepare](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content).

The page mentioned that *"the text of a com_content article can be found with $article->text"* which suggests this $article variable has parameters that can be used. However, there appears to be no link that further describes it. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

`onContentPrepare` is a Joomla article's plugin events, 
Means you can write a front-end plugin for Joomla and catch this event and alter the article content, or parse it .

It means

```
onContentPrepare($context, &$article, &$params, $page = 0)
```

The `$article` argument is getting the entire article Object and `$article->text` is the article content. You can check a sample [content plugin](http://www.walkswithme.net/joomla-plugin-development-tutorial) and understand more details from my sample plugin.

**Parameters**

**context** 
The context of the content being passed to the plugin - this is the component name and view - or name of module (e.g. com_content.article). Use this to check whether you are in the desired context for the plugin. (Here you can check specific view or layout to render your plugin means restrict the plugin to specific view or layouts)

**&article** A reference to the article that is being rendered by the view (For example: the text of a com_content article can be found with $article->text).

**&params** A reference to an associative array of relevant parameters. The view determines what it considers to be relevant and passes that information along.

**page** An integer that determines the "page" of the content that is to be generated. Note that in the context of views that might not generate HTML output, a page is a reasonably abstract concept that depends on the context.

Hope it make sense..

Comment: I am actually looking for the specs on the first 3 params.

Comment: The docs itself explained very well, check the edits  like content can restrict `com_content.article`. also the parameters have the additional parameters you can pass to the system,

Comment: Ok... so where in the article did it list all the parameters of &article, for instance?